# When to use a \mbox or a tilde for words that have to stay together

Tags: spacing

I am new to La Tex and wondering when to use a tilde, or a `\mbox`? A tilde prohibits a line break and so does `\mbox`, so when to use one or the other? For example, should I use:

```
\mbox{words to kept together}
```

or,

```
 words~to~be~kept~together
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 36):

There are probably other reasons, but I believe the space given by a `~` can stretch or shrink as other spaces in the line, while an `\mbox` gives you a fixed box, with fixed spaces.

And words joined with `~` can still be hyphenated, while an `\mbox` won't.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
A text with~some~unbreakable~spaces might stretch to jusssssssssssstify the line.
A text \mbox{with some unbreakable spaces} might stretch to jusssssssssssstify the line.
A~text~with~unbreakable~spaces~might~be~hyphenated~if~necessary.
\mbox{A text with unbreakable spaces might be hyphenated if necessary.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd add that `\mbox{...}` is very useful for avoiding line breaks in a particular word.