# Fixed-width interword space

Tags: spacing

I would like to typeset `post--World War II` with what Adobe InDesign calls a "quarter space". The en-dash is there to be wider than a normal space, to clarify the constituent structure ([post-[[World War] II]]), but in good typesetting, the two spaces in this expression should, unlike other spaces in the same typeset line, not stretch.

**How do I typeset a fixed-width "quarter space" in LaTeX?**

(I used to think that the right way was `post--World\ War\ II`, but I [just found out that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59260/14996) `\␣` isn't a fixed space at all but is just a line-breaking variant of the `line␣break--preventing` `~`.)

Really, I need two different macros: one that allows for a linebreak and one that doesn't. For example, the expression above should be linebroken in the following ways:

- ok: `post--`/`World␣War␣II`
- ok: `post--World`/`War␣II`
- bad: `post--World␣War`/`II`

(Let's just assume that this is how we want it and leave the question of whether the second linebreak option is typographically good or not for another debate.)

Let's also assume that linebreaking points in a component word are to be retained. Two examples ([from Wikipedia's "Dash" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)):

- "Fran·cis·co" in `non--San␣Francisco`
- "min·is·ter" in `ex--prime␣minister`

Related:

- about `~` and `\␣` (which don't help here): [Difference between control space and non-breaking space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59259/14996)
- about various ways to produce spaces in LaTeX: [Lengths and when to use them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41476/14996)

Comment: Should they prevent line-breaking as well? `\mbox{post--World War II}` See [When to use a \mbox or a tilde for words that have to stay together](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61866)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks; good question. I was meaning to write about this but then forgot. See my edit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just set `\spaceskip`; if this parameter is nonzero, TeX will use it for the interword space, ignoring the font defined parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\fixedspaceword}[2][1]{%
  \begingroup
  \spaceskip=#1\fontdimen2\font
  \xspaceskip=0pt\relax % just to be sure
  #2%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\WWII}{{\color{blue}post--World War II}}
\begin{document}

\makebox[\textwidth][s]{a text \fixedspaceword{\WWII} and so ends}

\makebox[\textwidth][s]{a text \fixedspaceword[.75]{\WWII} and so ends}

\end{document}
```

With `\makebox[\textwidth][s]{...}` interword spaces that can stretch do.

[image]

With the optional argument you can reduce (or expand) the interword space in the `\fixedspaceword` bit.

---

If you prefer that spaces are allowed to shrink together with the other spaces in the line, change the definition into

```
\newcommand{\fixedspaceword}[2][1]{%
  \begingroup
  \spaceskip=#1\fontdimen2\font minus \fontdimen4\font
  \xspaceskip=0pt\relax % just to be sure
  #2%
  \endgroup
}
```

The space won't be allowed to stretch, because `\spaceskip` has zero stretch component.

Comment: Is there a difference between `\fixedspaceword{\textsc{van Beethoven}}` and `\textsc{\fixedspaceword{van Beethoven}}`? I use `times-itsc` (which I know has alternatives).

Comment: The difference is in which font is used to set the interword space (the normal font in the former case, the small caps one in the second); it shouldn't be a big concern.

Comment: Question: What about a macro where the fixed space is adapted with font changes? Arguably the two "fixed" spaces in `Ludwig \textsc{van Beethoven}` should be different.

Comment: Is there a way of defining this so that the space will shrink proportionally but will stay constant if the text around it is stretched?

Comment: I would *never* use different spaces in "Ludwig van Beethoven"; about the second question, I don't understand it.

Comment: If I type `Ludwig \textsc{van Beethoven}\newline`, of course, the two default spaces (that is, spaces assuming no compressing or stretching of the line) will be slightly different. So it's natural to be wanting to apply this understanding to this macro. Would `\fixedspaceword{Ludwig \textsc{\fixedspaceword{van Beethoven}}}` do it?

Comment: About the other question, I mean: I would like the "fixed" space to shrink normally if the line is squeezed; but the space should still never expand. See here: `\documentclass{memoir}


\begin{document}

This is a long sentence filling up the line with uninteresting words, so \
This is a long sentence filling up the line with uninteresting words, so \mbox{uninteresting, so uninteresting, so uninteresting}.

This is a long sentence filling up the line with uninteresting words, so XXXX\
\end{document}
` A "fixed" space should shrink in sentence 3 but refuse to expand in sentence 2.

Comment: @LoverofStructure It will use the normal interword space for the main font after "g" and the normal interword space for small caps after "n" (which is slighly bigger, for CM fonts).

Comment: So `\fixedspaceword{Ludwig \textsc{\fixedspaceword{van Beethoven}}}` is "correct" usage :-)

Comment: Opinion aside, with `times-itsc`, I actually get slightly *narrower* spacing for `\textsc{\fixedspaceword{van Beethoven}}` than for `\fixedspaceword{\textsc{van Beethoven}}`; this surprised me (but I may have made a mistake in how I tried; I guess printing out `\fontdimen2` might give me a definitive answer).

Comment: To others: **Please see also the answer by user Werner.**

Answer (score 9):

The inter-word stretch and shrink can be adjusted (or removed). The following minimal example tries to highlight this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newdimen\origiwstr% inter-word stretch
\newdimen\origiwshr% inter-word shrink
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fixedspaceword}[1]{%
  \origiwstr=\fontdimen3\font% original inter-word stretch
  \origiwshr=\fontdimen4\font% original inter-word shrink
  \fontdimen3\font=\z@% No inter-word stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=\z@% No inter-word shrink
  #1%
  \fontdimen3\font=\origiwstr% Restore inter-word stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=\origiwshr% Restore inter-word shrink  
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\vertruleL}{\llap{\smash{\color{red}\rule[-10\baselineskip]{1pt}{11\baselineskip}}}}
\newcommand{\vertruleR}{\rlap{\smash{\color{red}\rule[-10\baselineskip]{1pt}{11\baselineskip}}}}
\newcommand{\WWII}{{\color{blue}post--World War II}}
\begin{document}
% \mboxed
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse semper 
mauris a odio vestibulum et eleifend quam gravida. Maecenas facilisis odio 
sed velit semper imperdiet. Nullam \vertruleL\mbox{\WWII}\vertruleR{} tortor metus, adipiscing sitalo amet elementum 
lacinia, ullamcorper at velit. Suspendisse nulla elit, bibendum a tempus eu, 
gravida non est.

% Plain
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse semper 
mauris a odio vestibulum et eleifend quam gravida. Maecenas facilisis odio 
sed velit semper imperdiet. Nullam \WWII{} tortor metus, adipiscing sitalo amet elementum 
lacinia, ullamcorper at velit. Suspendisse nulla elit, bibendum a tempus eu, 
gravida non est.

% No shrink/stretch
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse semper 
mauris a odio vestibulum et eleifend quam gravida. Maecenas facilisis odio 
sed velit semper imperdiet. Nullam \fixedspaceword{\WWII} tortor metus, adipiscing sitalo amet elementum 
lacinia, ullamcorper at velit. Suspendisse nulla elit, bibendum a tempus eu, 
gravida non est.

\hrulefill

% \mboxed
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse semper 
mauris a odio vestibulum et eleifend quam gravida. Maecenas facilisis odio 
sed velit semper imperdiet. Nullam tortor metus, adipiscing sitalo \mbox{\WWII} amet elementum 
lacinia, ullamcorper at velit. Suspendisse nulla elit, bibendum a tempus eu, 
gravida non est.

% Plain
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse semper 
mauris a odio vestibulum et eleifend quam gravida. Maecenas facilisis odio 
sed velit semper imperdiet. Nullam tortor metus, adipiscing sitalo \vertruleL\WWII\vertruleR{} amet elementum 
lacinia, ullamcorper at velit. Suspendisse nulla elit, bibendum a tempus eu, 
gravida non est.

% No shrink/stretch
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse semper 
mauris a odio vestibulum et eleifend quam gravida. Maecenas facilisis odio 
sed velit semper imperdiet. Nullam tortor metus, adipiscing sitalo \fixedspaceword{\WWII} amet elementum 
lacinia, ullamcorper at velit. Suspendisse nulla elit, bibendum a tempus eu, 
gravida non est.

\end{document}
```

In the first three examples of *Lorem Ipsum* text, the second one clearly has a change in the inter-word spacing, since the red vertical rules overlay the blue `post--World War II` with nothing else changed.

The dimensions relating to inter-word stretch/shrink are given by

- `\fontdimen3\font` (for stretch)
- `\fontdimen4\font` (for shrink)

The macro `\fixedspaceword{<stuff>}` stores the original stretch/shrink before setting it to zero (`\z@`) and typesetting `<stuff>`. Finally, it restores the original stretch/shrink. This allows for breaking across the line boundary as well, as shown in the second set of examples. `\mbox`, of course, does not allow this.

---

As reference, see [How to shorten/shrink spaces between words?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23921/5764)

Comment: Btw see my very recent edits to this question.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: I would say the "do not break" macro is `\mbox`. The breakable one could be `\fixedspaceword`, while the *author* should write `post--World War~II` to avoid a bad break of the numeral.

Comment: So `breakableprefix--\fixedspaceword{breakableword \mbox{unbreakableword} breakableword~\mbox{unbreakableword}~breakableword}` or `\fixedspaceword{breakableprefix--breakableword \mbox{unbreakableword} breakableword~\mbox{unbreakableword}~breakableword}`? Note that I have not tested whether an en-dash preserves the hyphenation points of the word on its immediate left and/or right.

Comment: @Lover Presence of `-`, `--` or `---` in a compound word removes all other hyphenation points. You can use `ngerman` shorthand `"=` for hyphen. For en-dash, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99336/11002

Comment: @tohecz About my comment-question above: The two seem to behave identically (with the hyphenation as intended, except for `--` disabling hyphenation on both sides in both cases).

Answer (score 1):

About two aspects of my (final, edited) question that both present answers (of user egreg and of user Werner) do not address:

1. With the macro `\fixedspaceword` from either solution, the following will do it for my expression "post–World War II" [<- Unicode en-dash inside, though it doesn't appear visually as such on Stack Exchange right now]:

   ```
   \fixedspaceword{post--World War~II}
   ```

   It is better not to use `\fixedspaceword{post--World \mbox{War II}}` in this case; see [this answer to a question about the difference between `\mbox` and `~`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61867/14996).
2. As user tohecz has pointed out, [this answer of his](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99336/11002) addresses the hyphenation issue for en-dashes (not handled by my code immediately above).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a custom command that sets `\fontdimen`, I found it simpler to use `\mbox{ }` which results in a fixed-width space.

Comment: This prevents line breaks, which is not what the poster was asking for.

Comment: Right. This is true. It was not an issue in my use case though because I wanted to have exactly the counterpart to a &nbsp; in HTML. :) Perhaps `\mbox{ }\allowbreak` would work?

Comment: The poster wants to allow breaking _within_ the material.  An `\allowbreak` afterwards doesn't help at all.