# Preventing line shrinking with raggedright

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

Sometimes with `\raggedright`, if a line is too long, but only slighly so, it will be shrunk instead of broken up. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\raggedright
\begin{document}
This is a line that is shrunk to fit the page width despite the use of raggedright. 
This is a line that is shrunk to fit the page width despite the use of \ldots
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to prevent this? In particular, I want all text in my document to be ragged right, and I want to make sure that everywhere in the document, text is never shrunk (neither stretched, but this is never an issue with ragged-right text).

Comment: I would not have guessed that as standard behavior.  Good observation!

Answer (score 7):

You could fix the inter-word spacing using some ideas from [Fixed-width interword space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99542/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\raggedright
\begin{document}
This is a line that is shrunk to fit the page width despite the use of raggedright.

This is a line that is shrunk to fit the page width despite the use of \ldots

\begingroup
\spaceskip=1\fontdimen2\font
\xspaceskip=0pt\relax % just to be sure
This is a line that is shrunk to fit the page width despite the use of raggedright.

This is a line that is shrunk to fit the page width despite the use of \ldots
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question. The proposed solution fixes spaces to one size for every font type and size in the document.

Comment: @RaggedRight: Sure. If you wish, one can add the specifics to `\normalfont`. However, I've grouped in the example, limiting the scope. If this answer doesn't solve your *bigger* problem, perhaps consider asking a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a possible answer to my own question. Apparently, TeX uses `\pretolerance` and `\tolerance` to decide if line breaking is acceptable. Setting `\pretolerance = 0` seems to produce the desired behaviour (setting `\tolerance = 0` does not). I am not sure how this works, or whether it will still work for other, more complicated examples, but it seems like an optimal solution for this simple example.

Comment: There is some discussion about `\pretolerance` in the [TeX Book](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (Chapter 14: How TeX Breaks Paragraphs into Lines, p 96; alternatively, search for `\pretolerance` in [`texbook.tex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex)).

Comment: Setting `\pretolerance` to 0 imposes stricter limits on badness of lines; it doesn't really guarantee that shrinking of interword spaces is avoided.