# What's the easiest way of putting a fixed-width space?

Tags: spacing

I got some Polish text with dialogues throughout it. I just learned that in Polish typography every statement in a dialogue is started by a dash *followed by a fixed-width space*. Now I have plenty of cases like this:

```
\textit{--- Jaki jest język wietnamski?} \\
\textit{--- Język wietnamski nie jest trudny.} \\
```

which produces:

[image: example of widened space]

It is evident that this is **not** a fixed-width space. I found some descriptions of how to get fixed-width spaces in some text in ["Fixed-width interword space"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99542/fixed-width-interword-space) but that looks too complex to me to be used in this case. Is there any easy way of changing these very spaces (these following the "opening" dashes) to fixed-width ones? Defining some fixed-width space (`\newcommand`) might also work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all ideas given above, here's the easiest thing to do: Just put `\kern 0.33em` behind every "opening" dash (every other solution demands some editing throughout the document anyway).

```
\textit{---\kern 0.33em Jaki jest język wietnamski?} \\
\textit{---\kern 0.33em Język wietnamski nie jest trudny.} \\
```

This produces:
[image: proper spacing]
However to change the width, all the editing work will have to be done again.

Comment: *However to change the width, all the editing work will have to be done again.* So, is this solution really easier than the accepted answer?

Comment: It is, as long as you are sure that you won't change it any more.

Comment: But the answer you accepted is more robust *and* less typing ;-) Unless you have just two instances of that fixed space.

Answer (score 8):

Put this in the preamble

```
\newcommand{\opendialog}{---\enspace}
\newcommand{\dialog}[1]{\opendialog\textit{#1}}
```

and, in the document,

```
\dialog{To be or not to be, that is the question}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\newcommand{\opendialog}{---\enspace}
\newcommand{\dialog}[1]{\opendialog\textit{#1}}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1cm} % just to make the text wrap

\begin{document}

\dialog{Jaki jest język wietnamski?}

\dialog{Język wietnamski nie jest trudny.}     

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\enspace` that makes a space of 0.5em, you might want to use a smaller one. The big advantage of using macros is that you can change the overall appearance just by acting in a single place.

Comment: Is it my eyes (or my age) or the curved serifs in `J` are not aligned?

Comment: @Sigur It's a misfeature of `microtype`. :( Removed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use some simple macro such as `\def\fs{\kern 0.33em}`:

```
\textit{---\fs Jaki jest język wietnamski?} \\
\textit{---\fs Język wietnamski nie jest trudny.} \\
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. load `babel` with your language in order to get the right hyphenations
2. load `microtype` which fixes many of those problems
3. put the dialogue in a group and put `\RaggedRight` in it. This will flush everything to the left. I would recommend to write a command or environment for this.

   ```
   % arara: pdflatex

   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \usepackage[polish]{babel}
   \setlength{\textwidth}{4.3cm} % guessing something which produces your screen-shot
   \usepackage{microtype}
   \usepackage{ragged2e}
   \usepackage{blindtext} %just for demo

   \begin{document}
   \blindtext

   \noindent
   {\RaggedRight
   \textit{--- Jaki jest język wietnamski?} \par
   \textit{--- Język wietnamski nie jest trudny.} \par
   }
   \noindent
   \blindtext
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Such a custom command could be

```
\newcommand{\dialogowac}[1]{{\par\RaggedRight\textit{--- #1}\par}}
```

But this will have no indent if you start a new paragraph.

Comment: here, `microtype` has the perhaps unwanted side-effect of shifting the dash out into the lift margin.  (there may be a way to turn this off, but there could be other side effects.)

Answer (score 1):

Would you use the unicode em-dash? In that case you can use some magic. Any line starting with `—` (the unicode em-dash) would take the next paragraph as argument and put it in italics (or any format you want).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\ifvmode\expandafter\bdialog\else\textemdash\fi}

\newcommand*\opendialog{\textemdash\,} % <- You can change here the \, to
                                       %    any horizontal space you want.
\newcommand\dialog[1]{\opendialog\textit{\ignorespaces#1}\par}
\long\def\bdialog#1\par{\dialog{#1}}

\begin{document}

—Jaki jest język wietnamski?

—Język wietnamski nie jest trudny.

\end{document}
```

*Note*: You need to leave a blank line so the paragraph is taken as an argument, for instance, after a `—` your document can't be

```
—Whatever.\end{document}
```

You need a blank line or an explicit `\par` token like

```
—Whatever.

\end{document}
```

or

```
—Whatever.\par
\end{document}
```