# Making the next space fixed width

Tags: spacing, white-space

I'm using the IEEEtrans document class and sometimes the figure caption

`Fig. n: label`

looks like

`Fig.  n: label`

where the space after the “Fig.” is stretched.

**How do I make the next space after “`Fig.`” fixed width?**

I have tried the commands `\enspace` and `\kern 0.33em` which I found on this link [What's the easiest way of putting a fixed-width space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263468/whats-the-easiest-way-of-putting-a-fixed-width-space) but neither works.

I cannot use the `\spaceskip` command as
proposed here [Fixed-width interword space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99542/fixed-width-interword-space)
because I don't know where to turn it off.
I need to fix the width of the next space but
not all spaces in the environment.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I use a non-breaking space in these cases: `Fig.~n`.

Comment: I though about this too, but I think that this would require me to edit the IEEEtrans class file, which I would prefer to avoid. I'll do it, if no other solution is suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could also use `\frenchspacing` if you don't want spaces of varying widths anywhere. But if you want to change just the space in figure captions, you will have to modify the macros that place them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IEEEtran` class has

```
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}
```

You can solve your problem by saying, before `\begin{document}`,

```
\makeatletter
\def\fnum@figure{\mbox{\figurename\ }\thefigure}
\makeatother
```

so the space after `\figurename` will not be influenced by the space factor of the period and be fixed because it appears in a box.

Comment: Don't you have to still add a `\space` (or `~` or something) after `\@`? The space in the input should be discarded, right?

Comment: @schtandard Oh, dear, yes! Here `@` is a letter! Thanks for noting.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue.